# what kind of delimiter to use for serialisation?

Tags: c++, string, serialization

I am building a ostringstream.

I was writing `int`s to this stream.

I am using `stream<<" ";` between 2 numbers.
I convert this stream to a string and UDP send it.

On the receiver side I am using these functions to split the string into individual numbers at the " " space character.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Now I want to write binary data, so
with the write function I am writing binary data e.g.
the data structure from here (http://robot.kaist.ac.kr/haptics/chai3d-2.0.0_Doc/resources/html/structc_matrix3d.html)

```
void  insert_into_stream(std::ostream& stream, const cMatrix3d rot)
{
    cVector3d column; 
    unsigned int byteCounter = 0;
    int length = sizeof(double)*3;
    char insert_buffer[sizeof(double)*9];

    column  = rot.getCol0();
    memcpy(insert_buffer, &column[0], length);
    stream.write(insert_buffer, length);
    byteCounter += length;

    column  = rot.getCol1();
    memcpy(insert_buffer+byteCounter, &column[0], length);
    stream.write(insert_buffer, length);
    byteCounter += length;

    column  = rot.getCol2();
    memcpy(insert_buffer+byteCounter, &column[0], length);
    stream.write(insert_buffer, length);
}
```

to the stream and separating each entry with a space character.

This doesnt work well, as if I add 15 of such data structures and then use the split method on the receiver side, depending on the data I sometimes get more than 15 strings e.g. 18, as the binary data itself might have the ascii space character inside it. Atleast that is what I think the problem is.

How to solve this problem?

---edit----
I add these 15 data structures in a stream, after I add certain ints at the start, so I need to use the split method to get these initial numbers.

Comment: Use a well-defined format with a standard parser. E.g. `json`, `csv`, etc.

Comment: You **don't need any delimiter for binary data**. Doubles always have the same length, not matters what's the number.

Comment: Why do you send them as string? Can't you just send them as bytes? This way you know that the first 4 bytes belong to the first number and the second 4 bytes belong to the second number. No need to delim anything. You just have to ensure 4 byte integers. EDIT: ups didn't realize you meant double (still same concept).

Comment: You can't use something that splits on space at the other end if you're transmitting binary data. The parser needs to be able to count bytes and reassemble the transmitted data.

Comment: "I add these 15 data structures in a stream, after I add certain ints at the start, so I need to use the split method to get these initial numbers" - then read byte by byte until you hit a delimiter indicating you've read your initial header, then split just that, then return to read the rest of your stream. Or, try `myfile >> x` for each of the 15 numbers, then `myfile.ignore(1)` the final space before the binary content begins (if you have one), then `myfile.read()` based on known sizes of binary content.

Comment: Just send binary data as said, if you really want to send your data as strings, choose whatever delimiter you want and use escape symbols, like in other formats, see `csv` documentation for example. Then you'll realize that sending data as strings is not as good as you thinked before:)

Comment: @Adriano That is, of course, false.  The size of `double` depends on the implementation, and in a file, it depends on the format of the file.

Comment: @JamesKanze I did **not say they're the same for all implementations** but that they **won't change**. First double you write in the file (let's say) is 8 bytes? After 1,000,000 written doubles you'll still write 8 bytes for each one. Then **delimiter is useless**, what you may need is a header. Of course things are different if you write records with variable length items (strings?).

Comment: @Adriano That said, it's clear you'll need to have a protocol definition and language bindings that are transparent for the machine dependent type implementations (that's what `int`, `double`, etc. are about), right?

Comment: @Adriano This is true for most protocols, but not for all.  There's no fundamental reason not to use variable length double, in the same way many protocol use variable length int.  And yes, the protocol _should_ define the representation of its types independently of any particular machine.  (Formally, at least.  In XDR, the representations do correspond in fact to those of the Motorola 68000 and early Sparc.)

Comment: @g-makulik Absolutely, a protocol is _always_ (strongly?) needed.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree but OP is serializing a raw binary representation of fixed length doubles (actually fixed size matrices). In this case I wouldn't use nothing more complicated than a well-known double binary representation. Many file formats don't encode data in protocols (if content isn't subject to change). Of course I agree again, as soon as he will need anything else then a strong protocol will be needed.

Comment: @Adriano _Every_ file format has a protocol (or format).  Some may not document it, but they still have one.  (Of course, in most protocols, the floating point representations _will_ have a fixed length, and your comments are valid.  But more generally, the protocol will define how you know when one field has finished, including variable length fields.  In his case, as far as I can tell, he hasn't defined any structure: the file may contain `int` and `double`, but it's not clear which and where.  His first step should be to define this structure.

Comment: @JamesKanze I can't disagree! When he'll write down what he expects probably this question will be obsolete 'cause he'll make both save/load match...

Answer (score 2):

If sending binary data, you won't use/need a 'delimiter'. You'll know how many bytes will be needed to write and read at each size. E.g. if your numbers are of type `uint32_t`, these will be four bytes from the stream.

But I see from your edits you'll need some mechanism to de-/serialize more complex data structures. I'd recommend using some more suitable protocol for this, e.g. [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).

Comment: A good recommendation.  Before that, there was always XDR (and BER, and a number of others): if you're implementing it yourself, XDR is probably the most simple.

Comment: @JamesKanze OT: THX James. Could it be I remember your name from some 'ancient' c++ newsgroups?

Comment: Could be.  I was one of the founders of `comp.lang.c++.moderated`, and have been active in `comp.lang.c++`, `fr.comp.lang.c++` and `de.comp.lang.iso-c++`.  The newsgroup format is far superior to what we have here, but they seem to be being abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.  The most immediate is that you are
outputting fixed length binary data, but trying to parse it as
variable length (partially) text data on input.  Typically,
binary floating point will have a fixed length (but it depends
on the binary format, and I've known exceptions).  Binary
integral data will often have a fixed length as well, but
variable length isn't that rare (e.g. Google's protocol blocks).

The second, and more general problem is that you're just dumping
bits to the output stream, without any format.  Which means that
sometime in the future, you almost certainly wont be able to
re-read them.  This technique is fine if you're spilling data to
disk, because it won't fit in memory, and the data will only be
reread by the same process, later.  Otherwise, you'll need to
define a format, and output (and input) according to what it
defines.  (There's a reason why `istream::read` and 
`ostream::write` take `char*`, and not `void*`.)